# C# Check if win function for TicTacToe

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, boolean, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to create an function to check if there is an win (horizontally).
So I thought this out on paper but could not get it to fully work. My code has 2 flaws at this point.

1. It only checks first row. and does not work after that.
2. Whatever is in the first row. lets say in point 0,1[X] 0,2[O] 0,3[X] it wil retrun that there is an "true"

Here is the code.

```
//Public Var
int n = 3;

//How I test if function is True and when. (every time an O or X is placed i do this:)

if (checkwinnner() == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Someone won.");
}

//Function
public bool checkwinnner() 
{  
    bool bw = true;
    for (int r = 0; r < n; r++)
    {
        bw = true;
        if (bar[r, 0].Text != "")
        {
            for (int c = 1; c < n; c++)
            {
                if (bar[r, 0].Text != bar[r, c].Text)
                {
                    bw = false; break;
                }
            }
            bw = true;
        }
        else 
        { 
            bw = false; 
        }
    }
    return bw;
}
```

So This is all there is to this function as of yet. Im buisy with it atm. So. I used an `bool` to check if someone won. true is win false is no win yet.

- N = height and with of field. its 3x3 always but can be changed trought textbox.
- R = row
- C = column

so I first put in an for loop to loop every row.
Then I check if text is not empty. becouse if its empty it cant be 3 in a row in a 3x3 field horizontally. After that i need to do a for loop for every column. and check if text in columns 1 is equal to 2 and 3.

However I stated my buggs atm at the top of the post and would like to ask:

Any tips on what I can fix or am doing wrong. I would like to use this code and not some if statement that checks the buttons like `if((0,1 && 0,2 && 0,3) == X || Y)` or something like that. becouse the field can be 4x4 and 5x5 to.

Thank you in advance. And I hope my question is formatted correcly.

Happy coding.

Comment: FWIW, you can just do `if (checkwinnner())`. No need for the `== true` part.

Comment: Ok so assuming its always square...... there are only ever rows, columns and the 2 diagonals.  if the same answer is in all boxes in any given row, column or diagonal then whoohoo else no.

Comment: Straight off - you initialise n=0, then in your function you set a default of true, and your loop checks row < 0, so you never go into the loop & exit with your defaultvalue. You need to learn how to use the debugger to step through your code.

Comment: @Corak: it wont even check that it will immediately fail the 0 < 0 check.

Comment: @PaulF - right, even worse.

Comment: Ok and @PaulF. Sorry that put it in like this. but that is not what happends. there is an textbox and i puti n 3 there. so the vallue. n = 3 always all edit it in code.

Comment: I would first suggest to find all possible winning combinations in the matrix first, because if you have no goals state, its very hard for you to do any comparisons

Comment: @Alander I know what you mean. but I try to create something that is tictacto+ if the field is 4x4 then its 4 in a row instead of 3. so how would i do that then. it has to be dynamic.

Comment: @Alander: the winning combinations are well defined - all of any row, column or diagonal have the same (non-blank) value - why would you need to list all possible winning combinations?

Comment: @PaulF exactly everything in the row has to be the same thats the idea. but ye im stuck atm.

Comment: One very simple answer would be to count all Xs & Os in each row/column/diagonal - if any count = n then you have a win.

Comment: I've done this several times in my career.  I worked for a slot machine company that I needed to verify reels on a screen.  The trick was getting it to stop at the first row, drop down to row 2 and move back to the start as it's at the end of row 1.  Once I got all the variables on the screen I used a template that had all the possible results and went down the list and verified what I had to what was a possible win.  I don't work for them anymore unfortunately but I did do something similar at my current job, give me a sec to dig.

Comment: @IamBatman sure thing. ill be trying stuff myself atm anyway i really want to finish this becouse its in my mind and i want to know why it doesnt work and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that after you loop over `c`, you're then setting `bw` back to `true`. That line will always be hit because the `break` will only break you out of the `for` loop. This is why you're getting `true` regardless of what you have in the row. The other problem is that `bw` will continue to get overwritten as the first loop repeats - you'll only ever be able to return the last value.

The following should work, is scalable, and stays as close to your original as possible. It doesn't tell you *who* won - you'd need to return some type other than a `bool` if you wanted this to also show who won.

```
public bool checkwinnner() 
{  
    bool bw = true;
    for (int r = 0; r < n; r++)
    {
        bw = true;
        if (bar[r, 0].Text != "")
        {
            for (int c = 1; c < n; c++)
            {
                if (bar[r, 0].Text != bar[r, c].Text)
                {
                    bw = false;
                }
            }
            //bw will remain true if and only if every cell in the row has the same symbol
            if (bw)
            {
                //if bw is true then someone wins, so return true so the method terminates
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    //if we haven't already returned true, there is no winning row so return false
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool checkwinnner() 
{  
    int size = n;

    //check rows
    bool okay = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        bool rowOkay = true;
        //start at 1, compare with previous
        for (int j=1; j<size;j++)
        {
           //this cell is blank or doesn't match it's neighbor
           if (bar[i,j].Text == "" || bar[i, j-1].Text != bar[i,j].Text)
           {
               rowOkay = false;
               j=size;
           }
        }
        if (rowOkay) return true;
    }

    //TODO (per Question OP): Implement columns and diagonals

    return false;
}
```

You might also consider changing this tell you *who* won ("X", "O", or ""). Otherwise you'll just have to go back through the game board again to figure it out.

```
public string checkwinnner() 
{  
    int size = n;

    //check rows
    bool okay = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        bool rowOkay = true;
        //start at 1, compare with previous
        for (int j=1; j<size;j++)
        {
           //this cell is blank doesn't match it's neighbor
           if (bar[i,j].Text == "" || bar[i, j-1].Text != bar[i,j].Text)
           {
               rowOkay = false;
               j=size;
           }
        }
        if (rowOkay) return bar[i,0].Text;
    }

    //TODO (per Question OP): Implement columns and diagonals

    return "";
}

var winner = checkwinnner();
if (winner != "")
{
    MessageBox.Show(winner + " won.");
}
```

For columns, just invert i and j: `bar[i,j]` becomes `bar[j,i]`. For diagonals, the top-left to bottom right diagonal is pretty easy (`bar[i,i]`). The other diagonal takes some thought, but as this looks like a practice problem I'd like to see you take a stab at it yourself first.

Comment: That doesn't allow for expanding to any number of rows/columns

Comment: This wouldn't be easily scaleable

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't going to become a triple A game.  Who cares if it's not easily scaleable then?  Just saying, if it works, it works.

Comment: Exactly thats the problem i had something like that but it is not scaleable

Comment: @IamBatman: Well the OP for one cares if it scales - so this doesn't answer the problem.

Comment: It scales just fine now.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn oh wow i see what u did there. let me test this.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  for (j=1; j<size;j++) shouldnt this be for (INT j=1; j<size;j++)

Comment: @H.Brendan: you shouldn't treat this as a code writing service - with a bit of thought about how this code works you should be able to modify it to work horizontally. Diagonals may take a bit more thought, and can be done with a single loop rather than nested loops. Working it out yourself is by far the best way of learning. Trying it out with pen and paper may be a good idea.

Comment: @PaulF yes. i know. im sorry. i am longer on this site 560 rep. sorry for even asking since i posted it 20 mins aggo im already trying and it works almost. and as you say. i learn more from try and error than copy paste. thx for the reminder

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn hey, i just wanted to say thank you. i fiddled some things out becouse of your answer so  i upvoted. but i found T Linnel his answer a little more understandable for me. i got it to work propperly using his code. so ill take that as the answer. sorry but still thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If you don't prefer to loop, I personally would use LINQ

```
string[][] grid = new string[3][];

grid[0] = new string[3] { "X", "O", "X" };
grid[1] = new string[3] { "", "", "" };
grid[2] = new string[3] { "X", "X", "X" };

bool test = grid.Any(r => !r.Contains("") && r.Distinct().Count() == 1);
```

Basically, you are looking to see if the values are all the same (but not empty).

Update, added the vertical test.

```
int n = 3;

string[][] grid = new string[3][];

grid[0] = new string[3] { "X", "O", "X" };
grid[1] = new string[3] { "", "", "X" };
grid[2] = new string[3] { "X", "X", "X" };

bool test = grid.Any(r => !r.Contains("") && r.Distinct().Count() == 1);

// for each column, get the distinct elements from it
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    bool vertTest = grid.Select(r => r[i]).Any(c=> !c.Contains("") && c.Distinct().Count() == 1);
}
```

Comment: Yes. but it is bound to a row. diagonal horizontal of vertical.

Comment: Right, modify this example for the others as well. You can still use linq to check the other directions.

Comment: but how is this scalable. lets say the field becomes 5x5. would i need to completely add more of the grid items manually?

Comment: I set up the grid just as a demo, the actual "check" doesn't have a dependency on how many items are in the grid. You could have 3 or 300 and it would work just the same.